# Finding the minimum of the functional

Tags: search, mathematical-optimization, minimum

I have to find the minimum of the following functional
[task photo](http://s28.postimg.org/6kj1h2rzx/opt.png)
Functional to be minimized is first integral, the rest are constraints
Here is what i've done so far
[my work photo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wert8hhw8h3j65k/2015-11-26%2021.57.34.jpg?dl=0)
I wrote Lagrange equation, calculated it with WOLFRAM. By substitution x(0)=0 and x(1)=3 I calculate C1. I have to calculate Lambda and C2 which is dependent from lambda. I'm pretty shure that in order to do that I have to use this integral constraint, but I have no idea how.
Maybe someone has any idea? :)

Comment: You should probably ask your question in http://math.stackexchange.com